# Jasmine testing nested angular promises not returning promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write get the test working that has nested promises. For some reason the promise is never returning.

For example

```
describe('Some tests', function ()
{
    it("Should complete the test with the nested promises", function(done)
    {
        inject(function (SomeService, $rootScope)
        {
            SomeService.somePromise().then(function(err)
            {
                 console.log("Message 1");
                 expect(err).toBeNull();
                 SomeService.someOtherPromise.then(function(res)
                 {
                     console.log("Message 2");
                     // Check some data
                     done();
                 });
            });
            $rootScope.$digest();
        });
    });
});
```

The strange thing is, if this test is run by its self it passes. But if there is more than one of these tests it fails.

When the test fails it seems as though the first promise is never returned. So we don't even see the first console message. 
My question is how to get this kind of test running and why is it not working correctly.